# Is it possible to do interactive user input and output simulation in VHDL or Verilog?

Tags: vhdl, verilog

For example, I would like to run a simulation for an interactive game like: https://github.com/fabioperez/space-invaders-vhdl without an FPGA, such that:

- signals are set by keyboard keys
- outputs can be displayed on a window

http://www.nand2tetris.org/ does this, but is uses a simplified custom educational language for it.

VHDL's `textio`'s `read(input` and `write(output` get somewhat close, but not quite:

- `read(input` waits for a newline, we'd want something that can detect is a keyboard key is pressed or not
- `write(output`: would need some way to flush data to ensure that the renderer that will emulate, say, a display gets it
- we need some way to throttle simulation speed

Of course, I don't need to do everything in VHDL: I just need a minimal way to communicate with VHDL synchronously with other programs, and then I can do the e.g. display with SDL in C.

Also asked at: https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/issues/92

Comment: In  [1.1.4 Hardware Description Language (HDL)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tkBLC.jpg) of the book referenced in your link, the V in VHDL doesn't stand for *Virtual*, it stands for VHSIC (another acronym). There's a distinction between [simulation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/simulation)  (1.2) and [emulation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emulation) (1.1). Without external resources as Brian indicates that V can't stand for Virtual.  You want to emulate hardware with resources not found in a simulator (or the VHDL language).

Comment: @user1155120 I feel that `read(` and `write(` already come super close to what I need. I don't need key or display handling of course, just a minimal way to communicate with the VHDL simulation, and then feed that to other programs that will treat keys / display things to screen.

Comment: If you do full detail cycle-accurate simulation, not sure if it will be fast enough to be interactive. Might require a very small core.

Comment: (OP, please don't add meta/voting commentary to questions, especially not at the start, where they are out of context for the new reader. They are not of interest to most readers - most people do not sign in or vote at all - so are probably best in the comments. I have no explanation for these votes, sadly!).

Comment: @halfer yeah, I know. I was being massacred here :-)

Comment: It's annoying, I got a DV on a Q&A pair just yesterday, no feedback - it happens. I'm a bit more philosophical about it now, I regard it as a natural phenomenon, like a rainy day `:-)`.

Comment: Aria from Nand2Tetris shows how to do it with Verilog, Verilator & SDL here: https://hackaday.io/project/160865-nand2tetris-in-verilog-part3-verilator-and-sdl2

Comment: Yes we do this all the time, as @BrianDrummond pointed out or implied it is not part of the language itself but the simulators often do have a foreign language interface such that you can use C or other languages to connect to the simulator and some combination of C code and HDL you can make an external connection, from which you can do anything possible in that foreign language like make a user interface.  Being simulated it is much slower than if you implemented in an FPGA or ASIC, but it should still function correctly.

Comment: Hi, all. I have a similar problem here. I wonder whether it is possible to generate some "software test/scan chain" here to manipulate some internal registers and interact with the environment. Verilator will generate private member variables for internal registers, and changing them across the entire project will be very difficult.

Answer (score 8):

**Verilator**

Verilator is a perfect solution for this application.

It exposes the Verilog simulation loop to C++ (and transpiles the Verilog to C++), allowing you to set inputs, and get outputs from C++.

See the CONNECTING TO C++ example from the docs: http://www.veripool.org/projects/verilator/wiki/Manual-verilator

So you can just plug that into SDL / ncurses / etc. without any IPC.

For a simulator independent solution, it might be worth looking into the foreign language APIs of VHDL (VHPI) / Verilog ([DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemVerilog_DPI)) as mentioned [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108243/is-it-possible-to-do-interactive-user-input-and-output-simulation-in-vhdl-or-ver/38174654#comment63651164_38108243), but there are few examples of how to use those, and you'll have to worry about IPC.

Minimal runnable example:

[image]

A related project that implements nand2tetris in Verilator + SDL can be found at: https://hackaday.io/project/160865-nand2tetris-in-verilog-part3-verilator-and-sdl2

Install dependencies on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
sudo apt install libsdl2-dev verilator
```

Makefile

```
.POSIX:

.PHONY: all clean run

RUN ?= move
OUT_EXT ?= .out
VERILATOR_DIR = ./obj_dir/

all: $(VERILATOR_DIR)Vmove display$(OUT_EXT)

$(VERILATOR_DIR)Vmove: move.v move.cpp fps.hpp
    verilator -Wall --cc move.v --exe move.cpp
    make -C obj_dir -f Vmove.mk Vmove CXXFLAGS='--std=c++11 -Wall' LIBS='-lSDL2'

display$(OUT_EXT): display.cpp
    g++ -o '$@' '$<' -lm -lSDL2

clean:
    rm -rf obj_dir *'$(OUT_EXT)'

run: all
    '$(VERILATOR_DIR)V$(RUN)'
```

move.v

```
module move(
    input wire clock,
    input wire reset,
    input wire up,
    input wire down,
    input wire left,
    input wire right,
    output reg [1:0] x,
    output reg [1:0] y
);
    always @ (posedge clock) begin
        if (reset == 1'b1) begin
            x <= 0;
            y <= 0;
        end
        else begin
            if (up == 1'b1) begin
                y <= y - 1;
            end
            if (down == 1'b1) begin
                y <= y + 1;
            end
            if (left == 1'b1) begin
                x <= x - 1;
            end
            if (right == 1'b1) begin
                x <= x + 1;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

move.cpp

```
const char *help = "asdw: move | q: quit";

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "Vmove.h"
#include "verilated.h"

#include "fps.hpp"

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 512
#define RECTS_PER_WINDOW (4)
#define RECT_WIDTH (WINDOW_WIDTH / RECTS_PER_WINDOW)
#define FASTEST_TICK_PERIOD_S (1.0 / 4.0)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Window *window;
    double current_time_s, last_tick_time_s;
    unsigned int current_time, last_time;
    const Uint8 *keystate;

    Verilated::commandArgs(argc, argv);
    Vmove *top = new Vmove;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, &window, &renderer);
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(window, help);

    fps_init();
    top->clock = 0;
    top->eval();
    top->reset = 1;
    top->clock = 1;
    top->eval();
    while (1) {
        current_time = SDL_GetTicks();
        current_time_s = current_time / 1000.0;

        /* Deal with keyboard input. */
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) == 1) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                goto quit;
            } else if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym) {
                    case SDLK_q:
                        goto quit;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

        if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE]) {
            top->reset = 1;
        }
        if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_A]) {
            top->left = 1;
        }
        if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_D]) {
            top->right = 1;
        }
        if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_W]) {
            top->up = 1;
        }
        if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_S]) {
            top->down = 1;
        }

        if (current_time != last_time) {
            if (current_time_s - last_tick_time_s > FASTEST_TICK_PERIOD_S) {
                /* Draw world. */
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

                {
                    SDL_Rect rect;
                    rect.w = RECT_WIDTH;
                    rect.h = RECT_WIDTH;
                    rect.x = top->x * RECT_WIDTH;
                    rect.y = top->y * RECT_WIDTH;
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                }

                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

                top->clock = 0;
                top->eval();
                top->clock = 1;
                top->eval();

                top->up = 0;
                top->down = 0;
                top->left = 0;
                top->right = 0;
                top->reset = 0;

                /* Update time tracking. */
                last_tick_time_s = current_time_s;
                fps_update_and_print();
            }
        }
        last_time = current_time;
    }
quit:
    top->final();
    delete top;

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

display.cpp

```
/*
Test a simple virtual SDL display, without user input.
*/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 600
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT (WINDOW_WIDTH)
#define N_PIXELS_WIDTH 10
#define N_PIXELS_HEIGHT (N_PIXELS_WIDTH)
#define N_PIXELS (N_PIXELS_WIDTH * N_PIXELS_HEIGHT)
#define PIXEL_WIDTH (WINDOW_WIDTH / N_PIXELS_WIDTH)
#define PIXEL_HEIGHT (WINDOW_HEIGHT / N_PIXELS_HEIGHT)
#define MAX_COLOR 255
#define PI2 (2*(acos(-1.0)))
#define FREQ (0.05)

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Rect rect;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Window *window;
    const unsigned int max_color_half = MAX_COLOR / 2;
    int quit;
    double current_time_s;
    size_t cur, i , j;
    unsigned int
        bs[N_PIXELS],
        current_time,
        gs[N_PIXELS],
        last_time,
        rs[N_PIXELS],
        val
    ;

    quit = 0;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, &window, &renderer);
    rect.w = PIXEL_WIDTH;
    rect.h = PIXEL_HEIGHT;
    last_time = SDL_GetTicks();

    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) == 1) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = 1;
            }
        }
        current_time = SDL_GetTicks();
        if (current_time != last_time) {
            for (i = 0; i < N_PIXELS_WIDTH; ++i) {
                for (j = 0; j < N_PIXELS_WIDTH; ++j) {
                    cur = j * N_PIXELS_WIDTH + i;
                    val = (1 + i) * (1 + j) * PI2 * FREQ * current_time / 1000.0;
                    rs[cur] = max_color_half * (1.0 + std::sin(1 * val));
                    gs[cur] = max_color_half * (1.0 + std::sin(2 * val));
                    bs[cur] = max_color_half * (1.0 + std::sin(3 * val));
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < N_PIXELS_WIDTH; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < N_PIXELS_WIDTH; ++j) {
                cur = j *N_PIXELS_WIDTH + i;
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, rs[cur], gs[cur], bs[cur], 255);
                rect.x = i * PIXEL_WIDTH;
                rect.y = j * PIXEL_HEIGHT;
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/tree/e50a6e9166ccd243c6fe3b7554bfe8dd1e4f9283/verilog/interactive).

Comment: I really like Verilator. I recommend it very highly. Ciro's point about not requiring IPC is a good one. In Connectal, we use IPC because the behavior is closer to what you get connecting software to actual hardware.However, for test benches IPC may limit performance or constrain what you can do in the testbench. I have ideas about how to extend Connectal for in-process connections between software and verilator.

Answer (score 3):

[Connectal](https://www.connectal.org) connects software running on actual CPUs to RTL (BSV, which can link to VHDL and Verilog) on FPGAs or simulators. [BSV](http://www.bluespec.com) is free for academic and research use and for open source projects. In any case, Connectal is open source and the software to simulator connection uses SystemVerilog DPI, which you could use in your project without using BSV.

Connectal has one example that displays the output from the FGPA/simulator on a display. It uses Qt to display on the computer monitor when simulating. From an FPGA it displays directly on an HDMI display.

CPUs simulated in Verilog or VHDL tend to be too slow for interactive use, but I have connected a CPU simulated with qemu to devices or accelerators in verilator or on FPGA. Performance of qemu is quite good. I think it would work for your purposes.

I added a plugin [FgpaOps](https://github.com/cambridgehackers/riscv-qemu/blob/master/hw/riscv/fpgadev.c) API so that the simulator or FPGA could handle CPU load/store instructions:

```
struct FpgaOps {
    uint64_t (*read)(hwaddr addr);
    void (*write)(hwaddr addr, uint64_t value);
    void (*close)(void);
    void *(*alloc_mem)(size_t size);
};
```

In my case, I used connectal to implement the `FpgaOps` plugin. This code is under hw/riscv but is not specific to riscv, so it could be used with any processor architecture supported by qemu.

Comment: I will have a look at those! The Connectal link has certificate problems, maybe it is HTTP only?

Comment: it is currently http only -- I suppose I should fix that

Answer (score 0):

No need for anything too clever or customised to interact with your Sim providing you're willing to simulate a real hardware interface like a UART.

The Verilog simuation of my TTL CPU includes a (reasonably) accurate model of a UM245R UART and the UART supports interactive IO via the verilog file interface.
One file for input and the other for output; bidirectional.

I use this for interacting with the simualated hardware so that I can develop the software and test it via automated test without having to mess with the hardware.
I even have CHIP8 games running on the simulated hardware and the CHIP8 GUI is drawn by sending control codes from the UART back to a graphics terminal.

The UART is here ...
https://github.com/Johnlon/spam-1/blob/master/verilog/uart/um245r.v
At some point I'll do a write up on it.